# What is the maximum number of permanent occupants in a Heathfire house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

Lets say you have a fully furnished house for Hearthfire. What is the maximum number of Occupants that stay there permanently, and what I mean by that is NPC's who stay there regardless if your there or not (also ones that are not following you).

From what I can tell you can have two total:

1. Whatever Housecarl they appoint to you (IE Valdimir/Gregory/Raayya)
2. Your Steward (whomever you appoint)

So ideally they will stay there and guard the place, when they are not ordered to follow you.

Is there any others? Like what about a pet (like one of the huskies you can get as a follower)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all the characters you can have in your house

- The housecarl
- The steward (somebody other than the housecarl)
- Your spouse
- The bard, hired via steward
- The cart driver, sort of (he hangs outside your house in his cart all day)
- Up to 2 adopted children
- Up to 2 [children's pets](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Creatures), which can be dogs or some other creatures: mudcrabs, skeevers, etc.

You can also have a human and an animal follower wait there, but they will run away soon after and you will have to adventure alone.

Comment: Can you have both a Housecarl and steward in the same house?  or can you only have both if multiple houses are involved?

Comment: Technically, you can get one more, though it's listed as a bug.  If you marry [Mjolll The Lioness](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Mjoll_the_Lioness) Aerin will sometimes accompany her to your new house, increasing the occupant count by one.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do the saints and seducers quest after getting the 2 pets which allows you to get two pet bugs(gained with the creation or special edition)
maniac elytra nymph and the
demented elytra nymph. you can get both of these.
but to maximize the amount wait until your child brings home a pet or you bring home  pet and you let your child have it. otherwise the children will not ask for a dog and will not bring home a random pet.
there is also the pets of skyrim creation whic allows you to get the following.
hilda (goat)
sweet roll (fox)
thistle (rabbit)
arachnia (frostbite spider)
skritch (skeever)
each one can obey a range of orders and each also has its own distinct attribute. Arachnia can place paralysis web traps and provide Potent Frostbite Venom; Hilda can provide Jugs of Milk; Skritch can locate or provide food items; Sweet Roll can locate or provide loot; and Thistle can locate plants which can be harvested for ingredients. Some of the pets can also be equipped with an Animal Collar or an Animal Pack, two items added by Pets of Skyrim; indeed, Hilda is already wearing a pack, and Sweet Roll a collar. The collar is simply aesthetic, but the pack provides a real benefit by increasing the pet's carrying capacity by 40.
and with the dawngaurd dlc you could also get the dogs bran and scaoenlog if sided with the dawngaurd. both unique husky followers.
or if you wish you could have the unique dogs CuSith and Garmr. the only death hounds that are nice to you and will follow. your kids will ask for any of these four.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please consider crediting the original source of your answer: en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pets_of_Skyrim_(quest). Also, the answer as it currently is written is quite hard to read. It would be beneficial to fix typos and separate the text into multiple paragraphs for legibility.